# Replace a single note with a chord

Tags: piano

I want to replace a single C note on the piano by playing a chord instead. How do I do that, playing a C major doesn't work.

Comment: It completely depends on what else is happening at the time of that C note. Please add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is the context? Do you have some sort of tonality? Or are you talking about literally playing a single C on the piano and playing a single chord on the piano? Please take some time to ask a good question, as you’d probably like a receive a good answer.

Comment: Welcome! This can't be answered yet, since anyone can play any note or chord they want any time; the "doesn't work" part will need more elaboration. Please use the "edit" button below the question to tell more about what you're creating and what doesn't work. It could also be nice to throw in some images of what you're playing using staff notation or a picture of a keyboard, but don't worry if that's not possible. Do take a sec to read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to get good answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).